# how do I get the count of rows in a appended/merged DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

csv1:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['Operations', 'PriceUnit', 'Cost', 'Billingdate']
data = [
    ['abc', 'USD', 45, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z'],
    ['xyz', 'USD', 30, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df
```

Output:

```
Operations PriceUnit Cost Billingdate
abc        USD        45  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
xyz        USD        30  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
```

csv2:

```
columns2 = ['Operations', 'PriceUnit', 'Cost', 'Billingdate']
data2 = [
    ['pqr', 'USD', 19, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z'],
    ['lmn', 'USD', 27, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z']
]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df2
```

Output:

```
Operations PriceUnit Cost Billingdate
pqr        USD        19  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
lmn        USD        27  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
```

I used argparse to pass the csv names while running the script. And used below code append those:

```
fnames = []
for f in range(1, len(sys.argv)):
    fnames.append(pd.read_csv(sys.argv[f]))
```

so far so good, but when I try to count the rows in the fnames using:

```
totalRows = len(fnames.index)
```

it throws below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rough.py", line 11, in <module>
    totalRows = len(fnames.index)
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your error is totally showing somethign diffrent than what you are saying you are doing. totalRows = len(fnames.index) is not len(fnames.count)

Comment: @JasonChia sorry about that. I was trying both count and index to get what I need. updated. Thanks.

Comment: `fnames` is a `list`. you should use `len(fnames)`

Comment: Firstly, what you are putting in fnames are the pandas dataframes returned from read_csv. can you try accessing fnames[n].index?

Comment: @JasonChia Both suggestions fetch the len (yours and abhilb's), but what I actually need is to create a new dataframe by combining/merging these two csvs and the its length so that I can perform some operations on it like get cost for specific dates etc.

Comment: made a typo in the df2, please add data2 and columns2 in the df2. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fnames` is a list of pandas DataFrames, if you are trying to know how many of them there are, it is enough to call `len(fnames)`
On the other hand, if you want to know the lenght of each dataframe, you can get the list of their lenght by `[len(df) for df in fnames]`.

To create a single dataframe you can use `pd.concat`, whcih concatenate pandas objects along a particular axis (default being index):

```
df = pd.concat(fnames)
```

At this point you will have that `len(df)` will coincide with `sum([len(df) for df in fnames])`

Comment: Thanks. What I actually need is to create a new dataframe by combining/merging these two csvs and the its length so that I can perform some operations on it like get cost for specific dates etc.

Comment: anyway I could do it using sys.argv? Because I want to pass the csv names from the CLI while running the script?

Comment: Isn't your code already doing that?  Once you stored the dataframes in fnames, you can concatenate them as above

Comment: No, the fnames here is creating a list, not a dataframe. @abhilb pointed it out.

Comment: fnames is a list of dataframes, once you concat them you merge them in a single dataframe. Also, I think you need to loop until `len(sys.argv)+1`

Comment: Right, I just had to concat the fnames: df = pd.concat(fnames)

It worked.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

# Dataframes
columns = ['Operations', 'PriceUnit', 'Cost', 'Billingdate']
data = [
    ['abc', 'USD', 45, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z'],
    ['xyz', 'USD', 30, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

data2 = [
    ['pqr', 'USD', 19, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z'],
    ['lmn', 'USD', 27, '2019-12-01T00:00:00Z']
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=columns)

# Merge dataframes
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])
```

Output `df3`:

```
    Operations  PriceUnit   Cost    Billingdate
0   abc USD 45  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
1   xyz USD 30  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
0   pqr USD 19  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
1   lmn USD 27  2019-12-01T00:00:00Z
```

Print rows from shape:

```
df3.shape[0] # 0 cause the first term is rows and second columns
```

Output: 4

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
len(fnames)
```

Hope that helps.

Just saw @abhlib's comment, will remove this if they'd like?